# TeamCity 5.X: REST Documentation

Tags: rest, teamcity, teamcity-5.1, teamcity-5.0, teamcity-6

[TeamCity 5.X REST documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD5/REST+API) directs us to a plug-ins page that is not TeamCity 5.X specific. I just recently realized this, and it seems that some of the functionality such as the [running:true build dimension](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-12957) are not supported until TeamCity 6.0.

Does anyone know where I can find documentation about the REST API for TC 5.X for reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can review [older versions of the documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/pages/viewpreviousversions.action?pageId=15803550) but not based on the TeamCity release numbers. You might have some luck looking at versions prior to the 6.0 release on Dec. 1, 2010.