# Team City Rest API - Getting running builds

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to use the Team City rest api to get a list of the currently executing builds. It seems like it is only returning builds on the default branch and I would like to get the builds on all branches. This is the api call I'm using:

/teamcity/guestAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=running:true&branch:(default:any)

Comment: possible duplicate of [TeamCity - how to get currently running builds via REST API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750963/teamcity-how-to-get-currently-running-builds-via-rest-api)

Answer (score 4):

found the issue the url should be:

/teamcity/guestAuth/app/rest/builds?locator=running:true,branch:(default:any)

Comment: Guest authentication needs to be enabled in this case. visit this link for more info:  https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Guest+User